# Image appears red dot

Tags: imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer 4.0.4 on my MVC website, I also use watermark plugin. But I've got one issue, the output image has a small red dot at bottom right. Here is my source and screenshot:

```
WatermarkPlugin watermark = new WatermarkPlugin();
watermark.OtherImages.Path = "~/Content/images";
watermark.OtherImages.DrawAs = Layer.LayerPlacement.Background;
watermark.OtherImages.ImageQuery = new ResizeSettings("s.alpha=0.6;format=png");
//watermark.OtherImages.Width = new DistanceUnit(35, DistanceUnit.Units.Percentage);
watermark.OtherImages.RelativeTo = "imageArea";
watermark.Install(Config.Current);

string querystring = "bgcolor=transparent;format=jpg;watermark=test.png";

ResizeSettings setting = new ResizeSettings(querystring);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(bytes, stream, setting);

    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't entered a license key.

Read more here:
https://imageresizing.net/licenses

and here:
https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys

Comment: This is a link only answer. Can you provide the main details from each of your links here? This is important as if those links ever go away then your answer can't help others. It is encouraged to always include the main details here and also include the link as an additional resource.